# Average trials until success with a linear increasing probability.

Tags: probability, reference-request

Can someone give me a starting point on calculating the average or expected number of trials until success with a linear increasing probability? For example if I have a base chance of success of $15\%$ and with each fail the probability increases by $1.5\%. (15\%, 16.5\%, 18\%, 19.5\%...)$. How many trials will it take on average.

I know $E = 1/p$ , where $E$ is expected number of trials and $p$ is probability of success. However I'm not sure how to adapt that to a linear increasing probability.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Arithmetic is probably the fastest way.  Incidentally, the probability exceeds $100\%$ on the $58$th turn so you might want to treat that as a guaranteed success.

Comment: $1+(1-0.15)(1+(1-0.165)(1+(1-0.18)(1+\cdots )))$ is a possible calculation which can be written in R as `sum(cumprod(1-c(0,0.15+0.015*(0:56),1)))`